# Probability distribution of discrete random variable $X^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is the probability distribution of a discrete random variable $X^2$, constructed from $X$? Is it going to be the same distribution, over a different set of outcomes? (If yes, is there a proof?)

Example: If $X$ is uniform from $1$ through $k$, then $P(X = x) = 1/k$. $X^2$ is also a uniform distribution over a different set of outcomes, $\{1, 4, 9, \dots, k^2\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$P(X^2 = a)=P(X=\pm \sqrt{a})$$

So for each $a$, you just sum the probabilities of the associated underlying $X$ taking the requisite values.

In general, if you are applying a function $g$ to a discrete RV $X$, then if $g$ is a 1-to-1 function of $X$, you are indeed just "shuffling" the probability masses about on the $x-$axis. However, if $g$ is not 1-to-1, then several values of $X$ may map onto a single value of $g(X)$, and therefore the distributions will not just be horizontal adjustments of each other.